# Solve the golden ratio-like equation $x^2-x-1=x\sqrt{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the equation for all real $x$
> $$x^2-x-1=x\sqrt{x+1}$$

This question is a competition question so we cannot use numerical solutions.

First I realized $x^2-x-1$ is a minimal polynomial of the golden ratio. Not sure how this will affect the solution.

Here is my approch.

$$(x^2-x-1)^2=x^2(x+1)$$
$$x^4-3x^3-2x^2+2x+1=0$$

$x=\pm 1$ doesn't satisfy the equation. Hence there is no rational common factor. What can I do now ?

Comment: Can you specify which contest this is from and whether the contest is active?

Comment: The galois group has only $8$ elements , hence there is a "nice" solution , but it is surely not easy. The polynomial is irreducible and the usual approach is to use numerical methods.

Comment: Sure. That is a 2020 year contest problem @MichaelBurr

Comment: [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E4+-+3*x%5E3+-+2*x%5E2+%2B+2*x+%2B+1%3D0)

Comment: OP is rude and ungrateful, expects everything to be done for them.

Comment: It is not ungrateful to seek the solution to the important part of the problem.  Pay attention to what I'm asking instead of giving empty talk. @AlvinL

Comment: All responses went much further than you did in your initial attempt.

Answer (score 7):

Let $t=\sqrt{x+1}\geq 0$, then $x=t^2-1$ and so we have $$t^4-t^3-3t^2+t+1=0$$ Now divide it with $t^2$ and make a substitution $s=t-{1\over t}$ in other to get $$s^2-s-1=0$$

The rest is easy I suppose.

Comment: Nice and slick!

Comment: Thank you, but the tricky part is to find valid roots . Not all roots are valid.

Comment: Can't you solve quadratic on $s$ and then quadratic on $t$?

Comment: Because given equation have just $2$ real roots .

Comment: So what?..........

Comment: Your answer is so nice I am going to accept but please elaborate if possible

Comment: Solve $s^2-s-1=0$ firstly. Can you do that?

Comment: My concern is we get $4$ roots but it is wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, you don't want to be guided. You just want us to do your homework. I can not help you any more.

Comment: How ? You do not cover the tricky part of that question. The main issue is to find valid roots not just calculations . Your calculations give $4$ roots . But it is not true

Comment: Can you write down that 4 roots.

Comment: Yes of course  .

Comment: @user1176861 Do you realise how long it takes for one to check their solution and type it here? Do you even understand how rude it is to say any equivalent of "..is this it?" in response?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ be the solutions of $x^2-x-1=0.$

We are starting from
$$
(x^2-x-1)^2 - x^2(x+1) = 0
$$
Rewriting $x^2:$
$$
(x^2-x-1)^2 - (x^2-x-1+x+1)(x+1) = 0
$$
Expanding:
$$
(x^2-x-1)^2 - (x^2-x-1)(x+1)-(x+1)^2 = 0
$$
Now we are using $\varphi_1 + \varphi_2 = 1$ and $\varphi_1 \varphi_2 = -1$ :
$$
(x^2-x-1)^2 - (\varphi_1+\varphi_2)(x^2-x-1)(x+1)+\varphi_1\varphi_2(x+1)^2 = 0
$$
Regrouping:
$$
\left( (x^2-x-1) - \varphi_1(x+1)\right)
\left( (x^2-x-1) - \varphi_2(x+1)\right) = 0
$$
which means
$$
(x^2-x-1) - \varphi_1(x+1)= 0
$$
or
$$
(x^2-x-1) - \varphi_2(x+1)= 0
$$
This can be solved with the quadratic formula.

Comment: Thank you. But the tricky part is to find valid roots . Not all roots are valid.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2-x-1=x\sqrt{x+1}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} x\ge-1\\ x^2-x\sqrt{x+1}-(\sqrt{x+1})^2=0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\\\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x\ge-1\\ \left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x+1}\right)\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x+1}\right)=0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\\\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x\ge-1\\ x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x+1}\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x\ge-1\\ x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x+1}\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\\\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}-1\le x\le 0\\ x^2=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2(x+1)\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x\ge0\\ x^2=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2(x+1)\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\\\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}-1\le x\le 0\\ x=\frac{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^2\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^4+4\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^2}}2\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x\ge0\\ x=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^2\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^4+4\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^2}}2\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\\ \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{3-\sqrt5-\sqrt{38-14\sqrt5}}4\lor x=\frac{3+\sqrt5+\sqrt{38+14\sqrt5}}4$$